# Como acessar o hardware no Linux em C?

Tags: c, linux, api

Sei da existência da Win32 API da Microsoft, que permite que o programador possa manipular recursos de baixo nível, como portas seriais, memórias, CPU, GPU, etc. No entanto trabalho com ambientes Linux e quero acessar o hardware no Linux utilizando a linguagem C.

Comment: Eu já li muito na web sobre o syscall, e não consigo entender nada :/ só vejo o pessoal falando de funções como o fork(), e nem sei o básico.

Comment: Pessoal que mexia com porta paralela, que usava os pinos da paralela para controlar hardware diretamente, precisava acessar apenas portas de I/O, e há formas de fazer isso direto no Linux e no Windows, sem precisar de um device driver. Para isso o documento http://tldp.org/HOWTO/IO-Port-Programming-2.html pode ajudar. Mas acredito que é uma solução totalmente obsoleta. Usar um Arduino para controlar o I/O de hardware, e comunicar com o PC via USB serial, é melhor em todos os aspectos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você não acessa o hardware, você chama a API do sistema operacional. Por acaso algumas delas acessam o hardware para você.

Windows e Linux possuem filosofias diferentes de como fazer isto. O que pode ser considerado equivalente à Win32 são as [*syscalls*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call).

[Livro normalmente recomendado para aprender "tudo"](http://basepath.com/aup/).